# Adding to the beginning of a linked list in C

Tags: c

I know how to add to the end of a linked list, but i don't understand why this code for adding to the beginning of one isn't working. In the memo for this specific question, they make use of a double pointer to the head variable, but i don't quite understand why that's necessary. Here is the code that isn't working:

```
void addtobeginning( struct node *head, int userdata)
{
    struct node *newnode;
    struct node *p;
    p = head;

    newnode = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    newnode->data = userdata;
   newnode->link = p;
   head = newnode;




}
```

Comment: The problem is that in C all arguments are passed *by value*, which means the value is copied into the local argument variable. And the arguments are local variables like any other, so all changes to them (like assignments) will be lost once the function returns. Please do some research about *emulating pass by reference in C*.

Comment: So you changed the way they did it, and now it doesn't work. Have you tried ... changing it back? Think about what the caller's head argument should point to after the call.

Comment: @Useless yeah, but they're asking *why* it stopped working and "because you changed it" is not very helpful.

Comment: If you change something, and it breaks, then thinking about what effect the change had is a useful way to start thinking about why it broke. And IMO learning how to reason about code behaviour is more generally useful than learning how to write yet another singly-linked list.

Comment: So what you're saying is that when you add to the end of a linked list, we only need the location of the head therefore a pointer to it is sufficient. When we need to change the position of the head, we require a double pointer to the head as dereferencing this will give us the memory address of the head, which we can then change? I apologise if i'm not being clear enough

Comment: You don't necesarily need a double pointer. Another option is to return a pointer to the new head of the list and leave it up to the caller to assign the return value to the "head of list" variable.

Comment: helpmepls I think you got it. Write an answer yourself. A duplicate question might be found, but if not you got a nice Q/A pair to your account. Just one detail, if pointer to start and pointer to end are identical (i.e. empty list), you also need a pointer to pointer to head to insert at the end. So, to avoid special case treatment, use double pointer in both cases. (Ian Abotts alternative is applicable however.)

Comment: This was almost four years ago, I just became an engineer now. Time flies

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you with the same task

```
struct Student* Add_Student()
{
    Student *p;
    p = (Student*)malloc(sizeof(Student));
    printf("enter name: ");
    scanf("%s", p->name);

    printf("enter ID: ");
    scanf("%d", &p->id);

    printf("enter address: ");
    scanf("%s", p->address);

    printf("enter avg: ");
    scanf("%f", &p->avg);

    p->Next = NULL;

    return p;
}

if (head == NULL)
                 head = s;
            else
            {
                p = head;
                head = s;
                head -> Next = p;
            }
```

Comment: In C it is considered bad practice to cast the return value from `malloc`

Comment: @EdHeal - I am really sorry for all the C newcomers. How to live with samples like: `fp->base = (char *) malloc(bufsize)` from famous K&R book ;) Or `int *pi = (int*) malloc(sizeof(int));` from Understanding and Using C Pointers ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to manipulate an integer with a function, you would need to pass in a pointer so that the function knows where the integer is located in memory. [function arguments by reference](https://www.learn-c.org/en/Function_arguments_by_reference)

```
void addone(int * n) {
    (*n)++;
}

int n;
printf("Before: %d\n", n);
addone(&n);
printf("After: %d\n", n);
```

If you want to manipulate a pointer with a function, you would need to pass in a pointer to the pointer(a double pointer) so that the function knows where the pointer is located in memory